# Firefox 64bit to 32 bit

Tags: firefox, 32-bit, 64-bit

Is there any way of downgrading firefox 64 bit (nightly) to firefox 32 bit without uninstalling it?

The reason is Selenium Xebium Formatter doesnt work on with firefox 64bit, but if anyone can find a way to make the above work with 64 bit, that would be much appreciated too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Is there any way of downgrading firefox 64 bit (nightly) to firefox 32 bit without uninstalling it?
```

No. They are different bits of software complied for different architectures.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, you can have both versions installed at the same time, as long as they are in different folders.